# SUM in LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Table products
ID    Name         Base    
1     Product_1    5
2     Product_2    4

Table orders
ID    Product_ID    
1     1            
2     1           
3     2
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT products.ID, products.Base, COUNT(orders.ID) AS Counter 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN orders ON products.ID = orders.Product_ID 
GROUP BY products.ID
```

to get:

```
ID    Base    Counter
1     5       2
2     4       1
```

What I want to do now is to write a query that's going to return a table like one above but with extra column SUM - sum of Base and Counter:

```
ID    Base    Counter    SUM
1     5       2          7
2     4       1          5
```

Is it possible to achieve this result using single query? I'd also like to order my results by SUM column.

Comment: Just add `, products.Base + COUNT(orders.ID) as Sum` after `As counter`  if we can assume products.base is numeric and then `ORDER BY Sum` after the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @xQbert Thank you, it is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Just add them together with a plus sign.

```
SELECT products.ID, products.Base, COUNT(orders.ID) AS Counter,
products.Base + COUNT(orders.ID) as `SUM`
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN orders ON products.ID = orders.Product_ID 
GROUP BY products.ID
ORDER BY `SUM`
```

Note: "SUM" is the name of an aggregate SQL function so you'll need to surround it in backticks in order to use it as a column alias. Consider using a different name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.ID, products.Base, COUNT(orders.ID) AS Counter, products.Base + COUNT(orders.ID) as `sum`
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN orders ON products.ID = orders.Product_ID 
GROUP BY products.ID, products.Base
ORDER BY `sum` DESC
```

Always include ALL non-aggregating columns in the group by clause. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

As you will see in that reference, MySQL has a non-standard extension to group by that allows for a relaxed query syntax. However the results rely on MySQL making arbitrary choices to achieve the groupings. Additionally if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting changes at any point if you follow SQL syntax rules your query will remain valid if you include all non-aggregating columns in the group by clause.

Comment: Generally I would agree but as products.Id appears to be a primary key based on the join to orders and sample data, products.base can only have 1 value.  So in this case mySQL's group by extension really doesn't matter. as there is always only 1 value for it to select from.  This is however an assumption that ID is a primary key.  per your link, "the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate,"  if there's only 1 value it has to pick 1. so it will always be the right one. so in this case not grouping by it may be faster.

Comment: Even if the primary key, if the setting value is changed the query can fail. So I firmly believe always is good advice on this topic.