# Should I use left join in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

(PHP) I have a database with a master table, and also a table that has values that correspond to a particular row in the master table. Please see a simplified version of these tables below:

```
table 'master'
id

table 'times'
id
master_id
type
amount
```

Some of the rows in 'master' have no corresponding rows in 'times', and other rows have multiple corresponding rows.

What I want to do is display the id from 'master', and then add up the 'amount' column for each 'type' in 'times'.

I've considered using a LEFT JOIN, where I'll end up with this (for example):

```
$query = "SELECT master.id, times.type, times.amount 
FROM master
LEFT JOIN completion_times ON master.id = completion_times.ticket_id
```

```
ID            TYPE          AMOUNT
1             NULL          NULL
2             "a"           30
2             "b"           20
etc. (hundreds of rows)
```

But I really need a result that would be like this:

```
array() {
  [0]=>
  array() {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "2"
    ["times"]=>
    array() {
      array() {
          ["type"]=>
          string(5) "a"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(5) "30"
      }
      array() {
          ["type"]=>
          string(5) "b"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(5) "20"
      }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write a SQL query that would accomplish something like this? Or should I just do a foreach for all the master rows, and make a secondary query inside that loop that will provide the corresponding rows from the 'times' table? Or perhaps is there another ideal way to do this?

Comment: Ok, why did I get downvoted? I did my best to write this well, and I'm happy to improve it. Please tell me what I can do to make it better.

Comment: **DO NOT MAKE ITERATED QUERIES!!!** Not my downvote, but where is your query with the GROUP BY clause and SUM() call in it?  I'm not sure where you are stuck.  Do you want to show all master ids?  potentially with a `0` count?  Where is your dbfiddle demo link for volunteers to play with? <- this is the surest way to get the best, fastest, most accurate support.  Also, have you had a good look around? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41230921/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516267/2943403

Answer (score 2):

A `LEFT JOIN` would be the appropriate `JOIN` to use in this case. Since you need to group by `type` in the `times` table (and that may be `NULL` after a `LEFT JOIN`), it's probably simpler to do the aggregation in a subquery:

```
SELECT m.id, COALESCE(t.type, '') AS type, COALESCE(t.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM master m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT master_id, type, SUM(amount)
           FROM times
           GROUP BY master_id, type) t ON t.master_id = m.id
```

Note I've added `COALESCE` at the outer level of the query to create printable values when there are no corresponding rows in `times`. You may want to leave that out so you can return `NULL` values in that situation as that might be preferable for your PHP code to test against).